# Is there a Javascript chart API with date object (labeling) support?

Tags: javascript, date, charts

Does anybody know of a Javascript chart API that will handle scaling and labeling for date values on both axes? It looks like I'll have to do manual client-side calculations for labels if I want to use Google Chart API.

My data set is potentially sparse in the dates on either axis, so intelligent labeling calculations would save me a bunch of hassle. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may wish to look into [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) for a JavaScript chart API. (I do not know if it will handle your specific labeling issue.)

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/flot/source/browse/trunk/API.txt - See "Customizing the legend"
It looks like you can pass in your own data point -> label function. Shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: For the git-inclined, I have a pretty active fork of flot on GitHub. When I started it the iola guys hadn't touched the official version in several months. GitHub makes keeping the project alive a lot easier. Cheers.

Comment: It does automatically scale the axes, even when they are timestamp-based.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Google Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/). I've never used it but I've seen people use it. According to the [examples in the docs](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/labels.html#chart_legend), you can put date labels on the axes.

Comment: I mentioned in the question that I'm using the Google Chart API -- for sparse dates the labeling calculations are a good bit of work. I'm looking for something that will do it for me.